# Is there any npx create react app equivalent for vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, npx

I want to install vue for my project through npx, not globally and to be sure that I have the latest version of vue.js, just like is done in react. What is the command in the terminal to achieve that?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### `npx @vue/cli create`

[Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/) ([`@vue/cli`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli)) is the equivalent package, which could be run with `npx` like this:

```sh
npx @vue/cli create --default my-vue-app
```

- Vue CLI 4's `default` template is a Vue 2 project with Webpack 4. Remove `--default` flag for version prompts.
- Vue CLI 5's (`5.0.0-rc.2` or newer) `default` template is a Vue 3 project with Webpack 5. Remove `--default` flag for version prompts.
- Vue CLI is now in [maintenance mode](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/7f3d51133635114528848b29e27084ee89d53e1c/README.md#status), so the following `npm-init` commands should be preferred instead.

#### `npm init vue`

The [official recommended starter](https://twitter.com/VueDose/status/1463169464451706897):

```sh
# npm 6.x
npm init vue my-vue-app --default

# npm 7+, extra double-dash is needed:
npm init vue my-vue-app -- --default

# yarn
yarn create vue my-vue-app --default

# pnpm
pnpm create vue my-vue-app -- --default
```

- The `default` template is a Vue 3 project that uses [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/). Use `@2` version specifier for a Vue 2 project (e.g., `npm init vue@2`).

#### `npm init vite`

A similar starter to the one from `npm init vue`:

```sh
# npm 6.x
npm init vite my-vue-app --template vue

# npm 7+, extra double-dash is needed:
npm init vite my-vue-app -- --template vue

# yarn
yarn create vite my-vue-app --template vue

# pnpm
pnpm create vite my-vue-app -- --template vue
```

- The `vue` template is a Vue 3 project. There is currently no official Vue 2 template integrated with this `npm-init` command.